# To hide Workbook tabs in spreadsheet in syncfusion

Tags: spreadsheet, syncfusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epx0P.png)I want to hide Workbook tabs in spreadsheet in syncfusion in c# in winforms.I have used.spreadsheet1.ActiveSheet.Workbook.DisplayWorkbookTabs = false; but Workbook is null in this case so gives object referance error.

I have used.spreadsheet1.ActiveSheet.Workbook.DisplayWorkbookTabs = false; but Workbook is null in this case so gives object referance error.